# Why does Blender 2.68 appear to still be 2.67b?

Tags: versions

When I download 2.68, unzipped it and then opened Blender, I got the 2.67b splash screen. I am on x64 Windows 7.

I am a bit confused. Which version of Blender have I actually got, and how can I tell the difference?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is much too specific.

Comment: Hi Craig, welcome to the site :). Sorry for any confusion.. your question has been closed as while it *is* ok, it is a bit localized and will no longer be really useful or applicable in a few weeks when Blender officially goes to 2.68.

Answer (score 6):

Because 2.68 is currently a [release candidate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate) and the renaming of the new version is not done yet.

If you look at the splash screen there is a number after the r.
It is not the same between the 2.67b and the 2.68 RC

[image: splash screen]